# PHP showing output of foreach to screen, for each item

Tags: php, ajax, foreach

One thing I have noticed with php, is that nothing is output to the screen until the script has stopped working. For the project I am working on I feed in a list of over 100 items and it performs a HTTP request for each item and when finished, shows a page with the status of each item, success failure etc.

What I want to know is if there is a way to output the results of each 'foreach' loop as they happen? So the user watching the screen sees the magic happening one line at a time or after say 5 lines.

I have only ever seen this done with Ajax type requests, is that what I should be looking to do instead maybe? Can anyone point me to a php function that does this or is it not possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may be better to store all script output in a buffer then flush the buffer when required.

For example:

```
<?php

if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

$test = Array('one','two','three','four');
foreach ($test as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $test;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Make sure you have mod_gzip disabled!

Answer (score 7):

[`flush()`](http://php.net/flush) should do it, or you can look at [all the output buffering functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `flush()` [command](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
flush(); @ob_flush();
```

after the output.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working solution:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);ob_end_flush(); 
@ob_flush();
echo '<div class="row b p-0 my-2 mail_progress" >';
foreach(range(1,100) as $k=>$v ){
    @ob_flush();
    echo '<b>|</b>';
    usleep(45000);
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What does it add to the other existing answers on this question?