# Force IE draw screen while completing a PHP call

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I have a PHP app that sends emails via the mail command (around 200) and would like to display them on the screen as they are sent, but IE only refreshes the screen at the end of the process. Is there a way to display the list as we go along?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201110/php-showing-output-of-foreach-to-screen-for-each-item

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at this question and it's answers : [PHP showing output of foreach to screen, for each item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201110/php-showing-output-of-foreach-to-screen-for-each-item)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't [flush()](https://www.php.net/flush) get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a long http session technique, such as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [PHP showing output of foreach to screen, for each item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201110/php-showing-output-of-foreach-to-screen-for-each-item/1201317)

Answer (score 0):

That would requiring changing some settings in IE I guess. The flush() command only makes php send the output to the browser, it can't control if the browser starts drawing immediately or when everything is loaded.