# Print Foreach Status on Every Iteration PHP

Tags: php

I m trying to iterate a `foreach()` loop and print variable on every iteration. But the PHP Scripts takes time and print all variable at once.

I tried below code-

```
foreach($to_list as $row)
{

sleep(3);
echo $row."<br>";
ob_flush(); flush();

}
```

But still loop iterating and printing all the variable together at end.

any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP showing output of foreach to screen, for each item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201110/php-showing-output-of-foreach-to-screen-for-each-item)

Comment: Are you running this through a web client -> server connection or via commandline?

Comment: @Anant I tried the method which you have mentioned in Link, But Still all variables are printing at once at end.

Comment: @SquareCat I'm trying to run via browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

$to_list = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); //example array
foreach ($to_list as $val){

    sleep(3);
    echo $val."<br/>";

    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

ob_end_flush();
```